# Почему тип функции не подходит для функционального интерфейса?

Tags: typescript

```
interface IGetObjectCallback {
    (data: any): void;
    (data: any, elapsedTime: number): void;
}

interface Fetcher extends IGetObjectCallback {
    getObject(done: IGetObjectCallback): void;
}
let a:Fetcher = ('data',3) => {
  
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgEkDiMoHkAjAKxhSgGEkAbKg1Aa2AG8AoUd4ACgBMkokAXMCQQAngEohANwD2YbgG42HEDz6DhYgDTAYVJAAcAzjG4AVMAFsYQiAFdLBeJOCz5S9gF9lIH+GjwyGjAAGK4KAAW8LoAHrAQ3EaYOPjEpBTUtAzMfuwA5riEJGQ8MhA2yYVpZJQ0dCj0Lm6Kft7sVLjCAmFQkdEAvFwA5Lz8Q1oAzOL9AHysKq0sQA)

Почему при таком коде получаю ошибку несоответствия типов при присваивании?

Comment: выложите сюда ошибку и опишите что хотите получить в итоге

Comment: Повторю заметку выше. Выложите, пожалуйста, стек с ошибкой. Без него непонятно, что Вы имеете в виду. Объясните поподробнее, для чего этот код и т. д. Просто выкладывать кусок кода без пояснений и стека ошибок с просьбой помочь - это плохое решение. Почитайте, пожалуйста, то, [как нужно писать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный вопрос можно разбить на две части:

1. как работает перегрузка в функциональном интерфейсе
2. добавление в этот интерфейс метода

---

## Как работает перегрузка в функциональном интерфейсе

Если в функциональном интерфейсе указано несколько перегрузок, как в примере в вопросе

```
interface IGetObjectCallback {
    (data: any): void;
    (data: any, elapsedTime: number): void;
}
```

Это значит, что функция должна удовлетворять обоим этим определениям.

В случае с

```
let a:IGetObjectCallback = ('data',3)=>{}
```

Передаваемая функция не совпадает ни с одним. Если добавить в определение типы

```
let a:IGetObjectCallback = (data:'data',elapsedTime:3)=>{}
```

Ошибка станет понятнее: тип `3` не совместим с типом `number`, так как по интерфейсу могут передать любое число, а функция может принять только `3`.

Если заменить типа на `number`

```
let a:IGetObjectCallback = (data:'data', elapsedTime:number)=>{}
```

Все еще не будет соответствия интерфейсу, так как передаваемая функция принимает строго два параметра, тогда как в интерфейсе указано, что он должна уметь принимать и всего один параметр. В этом случае решить можно с помощью значения по умолчанию

```
let a:IGetObjectCallback = (data:'data', elapsedTime:number = 0)=>{}
```

Теперь передаваемая функция удовлетворяем всем условиям и присваивается без ошибок.

---

## Добавление в этот интерфейс метода

Я не нашел нормального способа с помощью литерала создать функцию со статическим методом.

Поэтому пока единственный вариант, который я вижу - сделать наличие метода опциональным. В этом случае можно создать литерал функции без него и далее просто его присвоить:

Например:

```
let b: Fetcher = (data: any, elapsedTime: number = 0) => { console.log(data) }
b.getObject = (data: any, elapsedTime: number = 0) => { console.log(data) }
```

Интерфейс в этом случае будет выглядеть так:

```
interface Fetcher extends IGetObjectCallback {
  getObject?(done: IGetObjectCallback): void;
}
```