# Типизация декоратора или заместителя в TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Нужно взять существующую функцию и сделать вокруг неё обёртку, некоего заместителя, прокси, который будет что-то делать перед вызовом функции, но возвращать её результат как есть и передавать ей все аргументы, как есть. Проблема только в том, чтобы декоратор получился точно такого же типа, как исходная функция, у которой есть множество перегрузок.

Код:

```
function foo(a: number, b: string): number;
function foo(a: string, b: number): boolean;
function foo(a, b): any {
  if (typeof a === 'number') {
    return 0;
  }
  return !!b;
}

type FooType = typeof foo;
/*
type FooType = {
    (a: number, b: string): number;
    (a: string, b: number): boolean;
}
*/

const fooProxy = (...params: Parameters<typeof foo>) => {
  // Здесь я хочу, например, залоггировать параметры вызова
  console.log('Calling foo with params:', params);
  return foo(...params);
}
/*
const fooProxy: (a: string, b: number) => boolean
*/

const fooProxyTyped: FooType = fooProxy;
/*
Ошибка!

Type '(a: string, b: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type '{ (a: number, b: string): number; (a: string, b: number): boolean; }'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
*/
```

#### Вопрос

Как мне объявить fooProxy так, чтобы её `typeof fooProxy` был идентичен `FooType`, не повторяя при этом декларации всех перегрузок `foo` для `fooProxy`?

Comment: Попробуй воспользоваться декораторами (как возможность языка). Возможно тебе именно это и нужно.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOAlDgM5SkxgDmA3AFCiSwLKqbW30NKuAiVKt20eEhTpsiDGACe5RAG8WiTYlLEoIUkiiKADsTjB5iALw3EAcjxEydxAH5EAZX6NMKnBgA6ABtiRigAC1YAXxYWI1NEADFUa0R4swsZVhYQqGQARj46RlSZNAAWACZyVlzkSpxHUVKeOwUqAHdnGtiIBBpEQgxSHGS4VN55JSEFRWsAPjUNLT6wKjgQ4LgGX1YtbV19aR4MHpic3UHCxBpihlSh0grq2svCBuEnUgfhtDa1rqkOw1IA

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему тип функции не подходит для функционального интерфейса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1151159/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Это не подходит, потому что явно указывается один аргумент, когда когда у функции foo может быть и один, и два, и три аргумента

Comment: @NocteFury А как их можно было бы тут применить?

Comment: Ну вот два аргумента https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOANIoTgM5SkxgDmAlDnkWQNwBQoksBMlSZa9Rk0rVcBEqTZVUAG2IYwvftHhIU6bGoCeUnIYWHEAbx6JEMYIjRQDAB2Jx7GRAF4fiAOQccn4sltY2iKTEUCCkSAAMvDYAvmGR0bGIAISZhLwpPE6uiABiqN6IhW72urw8KlDIAIzssmTlumgALABMlH4AHsG89cjdOITKqkhewuh+ajQA7mR+lD0stRAIdFQYpDilcOWiiIbGp2AGZpfeAHyh4YhbYDRwKgB0SnBMmBthNmkYjoRBgpH98iNCM0ZJxSOVCHsur1-AAvIZ1KJUMaKN5TeGIvxQYh0VaIOIbIA

Comment: @LiquidSolid, декоратор может выступать в роли обертки над методом. Например если ты напишешь декоратор `@log` на своем методе или функции, то для него вызовется этот декоратор. В нем ты сможешь узнать, что было в него передано, подменив его своей функцией, сделать вывод логов, а потом просто вызвать целевой метод или функцию и вернуть его результат. По факту это получается упрощенная версия AOP. Можешь как раз почитать про него и то, как работают декораторы в TypeScript. На официальном сайте очень развернутое объяснение как ими пользоваться.

Answer (score -1):

без комментариев. обрати внимание на `// (parameter) params:`

```
q: {
    type foo =
        & ((a: number, b: string) => number)
        & ((a: string, b: number) => boolean)
        /** important any end type*/
        & ((a: any, b: any) => any)
    // ;;
    const foo: foo = null as any
    // ;;
    { let res = foo(1, ''), ch: number = res }
    { let res = foo('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
    { let res = foo('', ''), ch: any = res }
    // ;;
    qq: {
        type FooType = typeof foo;
        qqq: {
            const fooProxy = (...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)
            // const fooProxy: (a: any, b: any) => any
        }
        // (parameter) params: [any, any]
        const fooProxy: FooType = (...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)
        // const fooProxy: foo
        const fooProxyTyped: FooType = fooProxy;
        // const fooProxyTyped: foo
    }
}
```

```
q: {
    /** important any start interface*/
    interface foo { (a: any, b: any): any }
    interface foo { (a: number, b: string): number }
    interface foo { (a: string, b: number): boolean }
    // ;;
    const foo: foo = null as any
    // ;;
    { let res = foo(1, ''), ch: number = res }
    { let res = foo('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
    { let res = foo('', ''), ch: any = res }
    // ;;
    qq: {
        type FooType = typeof foo;
        qqq: {
            // (parameter) params: [any, any]
            const fooProxy = (...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)
            // const fooProxy: (a: string, b: number) => boolean
        }
        qqq: {
            // (parameter) params: [string, number]
            const fooProxy: FooType = (...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)
            // const fooProxy: foo
        }
        const fooProxy = ((...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)) as FooType
        // const fooProxy: foo
        const fooProxyTyped: FooType = fooProxy;
        // const fooProxyTyped: foo
    }
}
```

```
q: {
    function foo(a: number, b: string): number;
    function foo(a: string, b: number): boolean;
    /** important */
    function foo(a: any, b: any): any;
    function foo(a: any, b: any) { return null as any }
    // ;;
    { let res = foo(1, ''), ch: number = res }
    { let res = foo('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
    { let res = foo('', ''), ch: any = res }
    // ;;
    qq: {
        type FooType = typeof foo;
        qqq: {
            const fooProxy = (...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)
            // const fooProxy: (a: any, b: any) => any
        }
        const fooProxy = ((...params: Parameters<FooType>): ReturnType<FooType> => foo(...params)) as FooType
        // const fooProxy: {
        //     (a: number, b: string): number;
        //     (a: string, b: number): boolean;
        //     (a: any, b: any): any;
        // }
        const fooProxyTyped: FooType = fooProxy;
        // const fooProxyTyped: {
        //     (a: number, b: string): number;
        //     (a: string, b: number): boolean;
        //     (a: any, b: any): any;
        // }
    }
}
```

### Для невнимательных

```
q: {
    type foo =
        & ((a: number, b: string) => number)
        & ((a: string, b: number) => boolean)
        & ((a: any, b: any) => any)
    // ;;
    const foo: foo = null as any
    const foo2: foo = foo
    // ;;
    { let res = foo2(1, ''), ch: number = res }
    { let res = foo2('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
    { let res = foo2('', ''), ch: any = res }
}
```

### Для тех, кому нужно расширить обёртку

```
q: {
    type foo =
        & ((a: number, b: string) => number)
        & ((a: string, b: number) => boolean)
        & ((a: any, b: any) => any)
    // ;;
    const foo: foo = null as any
    const foo2: foo = foo
    // ;;
    { let res = foo2(1, ''), ch: number = res }
    { let res = foo2('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
    { let res = foo2('', ''), ch: any = res }
}

q: {
    interface foo1 { (a: any, b: any): any }
    interface foo2 { (a: number, b: string): number }
    interface foo3 { (a: string, b: number): boolean }
    /**import foo1 last */
    interface foo extends foo2, foo3, foo1 { }
    // ;;
    const foo: foo = null as any
    const foo2: foo = foo
    // ;;
    { let res = foo2(1, ''), ch: number = res }
    { let res = foo2('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
    { let res = foo2('', ''), ch: any = res }
    // ;;
    qq: {
        qqq: {
            type fooParams = Parameters<foo>
            // type fooParams = [string, number]
            type fooeturnType = ReturnType<foo>
            // type fooeturnType = boolean
        }
        qqq: { // РАСШИРЯЕМ ТУТ
            type extendParams = [{}, any[]]
            type extendReturnType = 'E_X_T_E_N_D'

            /**type fooParams = [any, any] | [number, string] | [string, number] */
            type fooParams = Parameters<foo1> | Parameters<foo2> | Parameters<foo3> | extendParams

            /**type fooReturnType = any */
            // type fooReturnType = ReturnType<foo1> | ReturnType<foo2> | ReturnType<foo3>

            type fooReturnType<T extends fooParams> =
                T extends Parameters<foo2>
                ? ReturnType<foo2>
                : T extends Parameters<foo3>
                ? ReturnType<foo3>
                : T extends extendParams
                ? extendReturnType
                /** important */
                : T extends Parameters<foo1>
                ? ReturnType<foo1>
                : never

            const foo2: <T extends fooParams>(...params: T & fooParams) => fooReturnType<T> = null as any;
            // ;;
            { let res = foo2(1, ''), ch: number = res }
            { let res = foo2('', 1), ch: boolean = res }
            { let res = foo2('', ''), ch: any = res }
            { let res = foo2({}, []), ch: extendReturnType = res/**let res: "E_X_T_E_N_D" */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это работает, потому что указывается `(a: any, b: any): any`, но в моём случае это недопустимо. Функцию `foo` по моей задаче можно вызывать только двумя способами со строгими аргументами и никак иначе. Поэтому данное решение им не является.

Comment: А что на счёт аргументов обертки, они такие же?

Comment: Да, аргументы должны быть такие же, обёртка должна быть идентична по сигнатуре к исходной функции

Comment: см (C) Для невнимательных

Comment: Я смотрю и вижу, что в одна из перегрузок `foo` это `(any, any): any`, что **не подходит к данной задаче** и без чего это решение не работет.

Comment: ©Нету ручек , нет конфетки.